# Python, Tkinter. How to start a movement circle after having stopped them?

Tags: tkinter, geometry

I am using Tkinter in order to make a simple application in which there are three circles that move around and at a certain time stop. I would make the circles start to move after having stopped them. I tried this code:

```
from tkinter import *
animation = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(animation, width=800, height=700)
canvas.pack()
x1 = 250
y1 = 110
a1 = 260
b1 = 120
x1_vel = 0
y1_vel = 5

coord1 = [x1, y1, a1, b1]
circle1 = canvas.create_oval(coord1, fill="blue")
def move1():
    global x1
    global y1
    global x1_vel
    global y1_vel
    if y1 > 550:
        y1_vel = 0
        x1_vel = - 5
    if x1 < 180:
        y1_vel = - 5
        x1_vel = 0
    if y1 < 90:
        x1_vel = 5
        y1_vel = 0
    if x1 > 430:
        y1_vel = 5
        x1_vel = 0
    if y1 > 570:
        x1_vel = -5
        y1_vel = 0
    if x1 < 90:
        x1_vel = 0
    canvas.move(circle1, x1_vel, y1_vel)
    coordinates = canvas.coords(circle1)
    x1 = coordinates[0]
    y1 = coordinates[1]
    animation.after(33, move1)

move1()
animation.mainloop()
```

This code makes the circle moving but after it stops, it cannot start anymore.

Comment: Your code is not testable. You are at last missing the definition of `animation` and imports as well as the definition of `move1`.

Comment: Thanks, now the code should be testable.

Comment: So how do you want to make it start again? Do you want it to be automatic or with a button click?

Comment: I want they start automatically

Comment: @GianmarcoPolizia This is due to your multiple `if` statements and the fact that `x1` is `85` and `y1` is `575` which sets both the `x1_vel` and `y1_vel` to `0`

Answer (score 0):

To start them automatically, add another `if` statement in `move1` function as:

```
if x1_vel == 0 and y1_vel == 0:
    x1_vel = 5 # change to random number
    y1_vel = 5 # change to random number
```

It is possible that the circle might go *off-screen*. So select a logical value for both `x1_vel` and `y1_vel`

Comment: Is there a way to let the circles stopped for an X amount of time and then let them start again?

Comment: yes. definitely. just add a `after` method when the `x_vel` and `y_vel` are zero. this will make the circle to stop for certain time